# How to persist the Process instance details of JBPM process into database so that on application start up we can recover process instances

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jbpm, java-17

I am currently using the JBPM 7.74 embedded in spring boot 3 app.
I want to persist the process instances kiesession into database so that on spring boot application start up the previous non-completed instances can recover from the specific nodes.

I am pretty new to JBPM.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.